# Kotlin assignments are not expressions. Any other way to force assertions to be enabled?

Tags: kotlin

I'm currently learning Kotlin, and one way I'm doing it is by automatically converting Java code to Kotlin and studying the results. One piece of Java code I tried to convert is the following static block in a class that tries to ensure that assertions are enabled:

```
static {
    boolean assertsEnabled = false;
    assert assertsEnabled = true;
    if (!assertsEnabled)
        throw new AssertionError("Please enable assertions!");
}
```

This relies on the `assertsEnabled = true` expression as an argument to `assert`. In Java, assignments are expressions. In Kotlin, they're not, and so this can't be converted. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Why not just do `assert false` and throw an exception after the line? Catch AssertionError and throw a RuntimeException; that way if you catch something, assertions are enabled (and the RuntimeException doesn't get caught)

Comment: @zoe That would work, but the Java code is more elegant in not performing the heavyweight operation of throwing an exception in the desired case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Kotlin doesn't have the `assert` keyword with its special semantics. Instead it has this function:

```
inline fun assert(value: Boolean, lazyMessage: () -> Any)
```

You can see that the expression passed as the first argument is evaluated unconditionally. This means you can't achieve the same lightweight check as in Java; you have to trigger an actual assertion failure to make sure.

So you need a check as suggested by `@Zoe`:

```
try {
    assert(false)
    throw IllegalStateException("Please enable assertions!")
} catch (e: AssertionError) {
    // Things are looking good; carry on
}
```

If you insist on throwing an `AssertionError` instead of `IllegalStateException`, you can use a boolean variable for that.

```
var assertionsAreDisabled = false
try {
    assert(false)
    assertionsAreDisabled = true
} catch (e: AssertionError) {
    // Things are looking good; carry on
}
if (assertionsAreDisabled) {
    throw AssertionError("Please enable assertions!")
}
```